# ¿Como editar un tema Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Instale el tema Master Study y necesito agregarle unas funcionalidades, para ello necesito editar la seccion de curriculum pero no logro dar con el html ni el php de esa seccion. He buscado en Apariencia -> Editor de temas, tambien en Paginas y hasta en la base de datos, pero no he podido encontrar el codigo.

En el inspector de codigo pude ver que al hacer click en editar (que abre la ventana modal que necesito encontrar) llama a:

```
 http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=stm_curriculum_get_item&nonce=a24d61436b&id=1169
```

Alguien me podria ayudar o guiar a como hacer para encontrarlo?. Desde y muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Los temas de WordPress están ubicados por defecto dentro de la carpeta de temas: `wp-content/themes/`.

Cada tema tiene su propia carpeta y dentro contienen todos los archivos de estilos, archivos de plantilla y archivos de funciones, archivos JavaScript e imágenes del tema.

En tu ejemplo con Master Study, los archivos que quieres modificar probablemente estén en una carpeta en: `wp-content/themes/masterstudy`

Más información sobre los temas en WordPress en su documentación: https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Desarrollo_de_Temas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Ricardo!, te comento que si estoy al tanto de lo q indicas, mi inconveniente es como hacer para saber CUAL es el archivo en cuestion, porque son 743 archivos y 234 carpetas los que componen el tema. Saludos!

Comment: Entiendo. No conozco ese tema pero normalmente ubican páginas y secciones en carpetas llamadas `templates` o `partials`, eso como punto de partida. Otra forma que funciona también es buscar por clases de CSS: se inspecciona la página de interés, se localiza alguna clase que identifique la sección y luego se busca en todo el proyecto por coincidencias. Eso último ayuda a reducir los archivos a revisar.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero poner en las plantillas la etiqueta de comentario de html y puedes ver en que fichero php es el que se esta ejecutando con el inspector de elemento.

Ejemplo

```
.
.
<!--- Este es la pagina que busco -->
.
.
```